# JSVC re-exec requires execution with an absolute or relative path

Tags: java, daemon, jsvc, apache-commons-daemon

My Class:

```
import org.apache.commons.daemon.Daemon;
import org.apache.commons.daemon.DaemonContext;
import org.apache.commons.daemon.DaemonInitException;

public class Main implements Daemon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }

    @Override
    public void init(DaemonContext daemonContext) throws DaemonInitException, Exception {
        System.out.println("init!");
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("start!");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("stop!");
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

I run jsvc follow document like this:

> jsvc -cp Daemon.jar Main
>   or
>   jsvc -cp Daemon.jar MainClass
>   or
>   jsvc -cp ./commons-daemon-1.1.0.jar:./Daemon.jar MainClass

It's also return:

> JSVC re-exec requires execution with an absolute or relative path

Who can explain this? 
Help me please!!!.

Answer (score 2):

Try specifying the full path to the `jsvc` executable.